# Place result of query into new table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL query which basically gets all the info to populate a new table but I am not sure how to go about:

1. Creating a new table but if it already exists then delete existing one and create again
2. Place all the data into the new table

and was hoping somebody could give me a hand or point me in the right direction.

Here is my existing SQL just in case it helps(Placed inside a PHP file):

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
SELECT
    'OverDue' AS ParentNode,
    'Documents ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '2' AS GroupLevel,
    'Red' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM 
    documents         
WHERE
    datenextreview BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'Documents ' AS ParentNode,
    InternalorExternal & ' ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '3' AS GroupLevel,
    'Red' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM
    documents         
WHERE
    datenextreview BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'          
GROUP BY InternalorExternal                     

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'OverDue' AS ParentNode,
    'Equipment ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '2' AS GroupLevel,
    'Red' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM
    equipment
WHERE
    datenextcalib BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'Equipment ' AS ParentNode,
    EqpmtType & ' ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '3' AS GroupLevel,
    'Red' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM
    equipment
WHERE
    datenextcalib BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
GROUP BY EqpmtType

UNION ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       


SELECT
    'Due' AS ParentNode,
    'Documents ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '2' AS GroupLevel,
    'Yellow' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM documents         
WHERE
        datenextreview BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'                 

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'Documents ' AS ParentNode,
    InternalorExternal & ' ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '3' AS GroupLevel,
    'Yellow' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM documents         
WHERE
    datenextreview BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'          
GROUP BY InternalorExternal

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'Due' AS ParentNode,
    'Equipment ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '2' AS GroupLevel,
    'Yellow' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM equipment
WHERE
    datenextcalib BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'Equipment ' AS ParentNode,
    EqpmtType & ' ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '3' AS GroupLevel,
    'Yellow' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM equipment         
WHERE
    datenextcalib BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'        
GROUP BY EqpmtType

UNION ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       


SELECT
    'Coming Up' AS ParentNode,
    'Documents ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '2' AS GroupLevel,
    'Green' AS ImageNamePrefix
FROM  documents        
WHERE
    datenextreview BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'Documents ' AS ParentNode,
    InternalorExternal &  ' ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '3' AS GroupLevel,
    'Green' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM documents
WHERE
    datenextreview BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
GROUP BY InternalorExternal

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'Coming Up' AS ParentNode,
    'Equipment ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '2' AS GroupLevel,
    'Green' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM  equipment
WHERE
    datenextcalib BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'

UNION ALL                    
SELECT
    'Equipment ' AS ParentNode,
    EqpmtType &   ' ' AS ChildNode,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfFails,
    '3' AS GroupLevel,
    'Green' AS ImageNamePrefix         
FROM equipment
WHERE
    datenextcalib BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
GROUP BY EqpmtType
) AS table2              
ORDER BY         
 GroupLevel,
 ChildNode DESC,
 ParentNode DESC
```

I tried using the format:

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table_name
FROM [query]
```

on the above query, but it just displays `Invalid query: Undeclared variable: new_table_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO newTable (ChildNode, NoOfFails, GroupLevel, ImageNamePrefix)
SELECT ... -- paste your SELECT STATEMENT HERE (the one you posted)
```

From the MySQL Doc, `SELECT INTO` is not supported by the server.

**[Read About This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)** 
**[INSERT INTO...SELECT](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html)**

Comment: Correct. MySQL doesn't support the `SELECT INTO` syntax. Note that the table has exist for this code to work (which is fine, just different from how `SELECT INTO` works)

Comment: yeah was just about to say that, does this mean I would need a separate query for creating the table now?

Comment: indeed you need to create separate query for that.